# Can't stream Airplay from Iphone Youtube app

Tags: ios, airplay, youtube

My setup:

- Iphone 6, with iOS 8.1.2.
- Mac Mini with OS X 10.6.8 and Airserver 5.0.7.

I can stream any video in my Iphone to the Mac Mini using Airplay. I can also stream from the iOS Vimeo app, as well as pretty much every other one. However, when it comes to the Youtube app, whenever I try to stream using Airplay I get an error in the Mac Mini saying "a data reference could not be cleared".

What's up? Is this Youtube's DRM, or is there something else going on?

Comment: not all youtube are DRM protected, try some.

Comment: Nope. Just tried with a Youtube video that did not have DRM, and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Is it just streaming or you can play directly on mac mini or iphone?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I can watch any video in the Youtube app on my Iphone, no problem. I can also open Safari in the Mac Mini, go to Youtube and watch any video. It's only when I try to stream using Airplay from my Iphone to the Mac that there's the problem.